# LVM vs ZFS (vs BTRFS) for home file server

Tags: filesystems, lvm, zfs, network-attached-storage, mirror

I am rebuilding my small fileserver (Athlon 5350 + 4GB ddr3 running CentOS 7) replacing several second-hand hard driver with WD Red.
The server is mainly used for personal files (documents, pictures), media files (music and videos) and othe rsoftware (VM images, iso, installers etc..)

I want to mirror personal files and to dynamically expand the array adding new drives or resising partitions e.g.:
given 2 TB HDD I want 2 mirrored 500GB partitions and 2 1,5TB stripped/JBOD partitions for other files with the chance to add 2/4TB hdds in future.

To achieve this which is the better solution in terms performance (ZFS should be memory hungry), reliability and which is easier to use? I read also about BTRFS does it have some advantages over ZFS?

Another question: when I lose an hdd in a LVM group all data ase lost, is the same with ZFS or is it possible to split entire files on different partition and recover at least a part of data?

Thank you!